# Nested tables in Vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I am learning VueJs, but I'm struggling to create the following markup and keep it semantically correct. I want to use a `v-for` loop to repeat the 2 components - but where do I put it? I can't add it to the `tbody` as that can't repeat. If I add loops to both the `tr` rows I end up with component1 repeated n times, followed by component2 repeated n times.  Semantically I can't use a span or a div (unless it's inside a `td` element) and components must have a single root. Advice appreciated.

```
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="component1">
            <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="component2">
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>
                    ...
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<body><template v-for="component in components"><tr.. .. tr></template></tbody>`

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, I didn't realize I could use a `template` element outside of a component. I knew there had to be a way!

Comment: np, if they are actual vue components, you could also use `<component v-bind:is="component1"` then let them render the tr's see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Thanks. I did look at that, but I would still need the `template` tag to wrap the `v-for` as I  need a single `tr` root element, no?

Comment: na `tbody><component v-for=...></component></tbody>`

Comment: also if its not a component, you could do `<tr :class="\`component${index+1}\`" v-for="(v, index) in ..">`

Comment: They are actual components, I just simplified them as `tr`s in the above, but still puzzled over your answer - even with a dynamic component I need 2 consecutive `tr`s or do dynamic components not require a single root?

Comment: see answer and example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are components, just loop through them.

```js
let components = {
  component1: {
    template: '#component1'
  },
  component2: {
    template: '#component2'
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:() => ({
   components
  })
})
```

```css
td{border:1px solid orange}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <component :is="component" v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="index"></component>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<template id="component1">
  <tr class="component1">
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
   </tr>
</template>

<template id="component2">
  <tr class="component2">
    <td colspan="3">
      <table>
        ...
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

If there is not a good reason to use a table you should use divs, tables are not for designing layouts.

Comment: But surely I still need the `template` tag to wrap the `component`, or I'll be limited to just the 2 rows (components)?

Comment: what do you mean by wrap? the components above are wrapped in `<template>`, if you add component3 it will loop out like the others.

Comment: My (main) table has more than 2 rows, each comprised of 2 consecutive components (1 &2). Basically it's the answer Paulo gave below, but using a `template` tag instead of the `div` that he suggested (which is invalid)...

Comment: if your talking about root element, as long as its a real element and there is only one its fine, i.e `<template><tr></tr><tr></tr></template>` wont work

Comment: a component can call a component if you mean to switch out `<table>...</table>` for a component.

Comment: it would help if you gave a better example

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
<table border=1>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<div v-for="index in 10" :key="index" >
  <tr class="component1">
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="component2">
        <td colspan="3">
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Barbosa, but to keep it semantically correct - `div`s can only live inside of table cells `td`s